# Java for loop not completing properly

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Ok, so I'm trying to add an array of 64 JButtons to a JFrame with and 8 by 8 grid layout (chess board type thing). Here's the relevant code section:

```
public class othello implements ActionListener{
int [][] board = new int[8][8];
JFrame window = new JFrame();
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[64];

public othello(){

window.setSize(400,400);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
window.setVisible(true);
    for (int i=0;i<64;i++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton("");
        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        window.add(buttons[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<8;j++){
            board[i][j]=2;
        }
    }
    board[3][3]=0;board[4][4]=0;
    board[3][4]=1;board[4][3]=1;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<8;j++){
            if(e.getSource()==buttons[i]){
                buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
                board[i][j]=1;
                check();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    new othello();
}
```

}

What this code results in is a seemingly random number of buttons actually being added. Occasionally it adds all 64, more commonly it adds perhaps half or so, it always starts properly but stops at an arbitrary point (I tested by having the button labels count up).

I added some println's to see if the loop itself was actually completing, no problem there, it's going round the loop all 64 times, it just stops adding buttons at some point.

I'm something of a beginner at Java so I'm sure it's something really simple and stupid, but I currently have no idea what's going wrong. Can anyone help?

Edited for more code.

Comment: are you sure it's not just adding buttons off the screen and you can't see them?  without more code we probably aren't going to be able to help you.  How is `window` defined?

Comment: What is `buttons`? (List, ArrayList, etc.)

Comment: Did the program exit with an exception?

Comment: Is the code being run in a headless environment?

Comment: window is just a JFrame, buttons is an array of JButtons:
JFrame window = new JFrame();
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[64];
The program runs without throwing any exceptions, only the window.add(buttons[i]); part doesn't function properly.

Comment: I'll add more relevant code, cleaning it of anything unrelated.

Comment: Did you pack the JFrame before displaying?

Answer (score 1):

Have you initializated the array? like

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButtons[x];
```

make some prints to check in what number the loop stops.

Comment: "I added some println's to see if the loop itself was actually completing, no problem there, it's going round the loop all 64 times, it just stops adding buttons at some point."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) to manipulate the UI?

From the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/):

> The event dispatch thread, where all event-handling code is executed.
>   Most code that interacts with the Swing framework must also execute on
>   this thread.

Try to run your UI construction code using `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`.

Edit: the corrected source code would be:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class othello implements ActionListener
{
    int[][] board = new int[8][8];
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[64];

    public othello()
    {
        try
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    window.setSize(400, 400);
                    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    window.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
                    window.setVisible(true);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
                    {
                        buttons[i] = new JButton("");
                        buttons[i].addActionListener(othello.this);
                        window.getContentPane().add(buttons[i]);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                        {
                            board[i][j] = 2;
                        }
                    }
                    board[3][3] = 0;
                    board[4][4] = 0;
                    board[3][4] = 1;
                    board[4][3] = 1;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if (e.getSource() == buttons[i])
                {
                    buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
                    board[i][j] = 1;
                    // check();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new othello();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. From the println's I had a vague inkling of what sort of thing wasn't happening, but I'm not at the stage where I can make the link to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding to a ContentPane not directly to a `JFrame.add()`

> Like all other JFC/Swing top-level containers, a JFrame contains a
>   JRootPane as its only child. The content pane provided by the root
>   pane should, as a rule, contain all the non-menu components displayed
>   by the JFrame.

Are you setting the layout manager to something other than the default?

> The default content pane will have a BorderLayout manager set on it.
>   Refer to RootPaneContainer for details on adding, removing and setting
>   the LayoutManager of a JFrame.

the proper idiomatic code to add contents is as follows:

```
window.getContentPane().add(child);
```

Refer to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) for details on proper use.